# Use regular expression to handle nested parenthesis in math equation?

Tags: python, regex

If I have:

```
statement = "(2*(3+1))*2"
```

I want to be able to handle multiple parentheses within parentheses for a math reader I'm writing. Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, but my goal was to recursively go deeper into the parentheses until there were none, and then I would perform the math operations. Thus, I would first want to focus on

```
"(2*(3+1))"
```

then focus on

```
"(3+1)"
```

I hoped to do this by assigning the focus value to the start index of the regex and the end index of the regex. I have yet to figure out how to find the end index, but I'm more interested in first matching the regex

```
r"\(.+\)"
```

failed to match. I wanted it to read as "any one or more characters contained within a set of parentheses". Could someone explain why the above expression will not match to the above statement in python?

Comment: [`r"\(.+\)"` does match.](http://ideone.com/oJQjV)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I love regular expressions.  I use them all the time.

Don't use regular expressions for this.

You want an actual parser that will actually parse your math expressions.  You might want to read this:

http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm

Once you have actually parsed the expression, it's trivial to walk the parse tree and compute the result.

EDIT: @Lattyware suggested pyparsing, which should also be a good way to go, and might be easier than the EFFBot solution posted above.

https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Here's a direct link to the pyparsing sample code for a four-function algebraic expression evaluator:

http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning [``pyparsing``](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) - although if this is all that is wanted, it would be overkill.

Comment: @Lattyware So would you recommend using pyparsing if I wanted to use my python program to parse a file and interpret its content as if it were code in another language?

Comment: @purpleladydragons, pyparsing is a kit for building any parser you need.  The sample code for pyparsing includes a "four-function algebraic notation parser" so that would give you a starting point: http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py

Comment: Now that I have read the pyparsing web page a bit, I think that looks like a good candidate for you to use.  It has a generous license so you can probably use it for whatever you are doing.  I will edit the answer to suggest pyparsing.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 2):

for what it's worth, here's a little more context:

regular expressions are called "regular" because they're associated with regular grammars, and regular grammars cannot describe (an unlimited number of) nested parentheses (they can describe a bunch of random parentheses, but cannot make them match in neat pairs).

one way to understand this is to understand that regular expressions can (modulo some details which i will explain at the end) be converted to deterministic finite automatons.  which sounds intimidating but really just means that they can be converted into lists of "rules", where the rules depend on what you matched, and describe what you can match.

for example, the regular expression `ab*c` can be converted to:

1. at the start, you can only match `a`.  then go to 2.
2. now, you can match `b` and go back to 2, or match `c` and go to 3
3. you're done!  the match was a success!

and that is a "deterministic finite automaton".

anyway, the interesting part of this is that if you sit down and try to make something like that for matching pairs of parentheses you can't!  try it.  you can match a finite number by making more and more rules, but you can't write a general set of rules that match an unlimited number of parentheses (i should add that the rules have to be of the form "if you match X go to Y").

now obviously you could modify that in various ways.  you could allow more complex rules (like extending them to let you keep a count of the parentheses), and you could then get something that worked as you expect.  but it wouldn't be a regular grammar.

given that regular expressions are limited in this way, why are they used rather than something more complex?  it turns out that they're something of a sweet spot - they can do a lot, while remaining fairly simple and efficient.  more complex grammars (kinds of rules) can be more powerful, but are also harder to implement, and have more problems with efficiency.

final disclaimer and promised extra details: in practice many regular expressions these days actually *are* more powerful than this (and should not really be called "regular expressions").  but the above is still the basic explanation of why you should not use a regexp for this.

ps jesse's suggested solution gets round this by using a regexp multiple times; the argument here is for a single use of the regexp.

Comment: The terse summary of the above: "regular expressions cannot count".  It will take a lot of work, repeatedly applying regular expressions, to make them handle expressions with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I probably agree with steveha, and don't recommend regex for this, but to answer your question specifically, you need unescaped parens to pull out results groups (your pattern only has escaped parens):

```
>>> re.match(r"\((.+)\)", "(2*(3+1))*2").group(1)
'2*(3+1)'
```

If you go that route, you could iterate over the match results until you run out of matches, and then reverse the results list to work inside out.