# Find all strings in nested brackets

Tags: python, regex, string

How do i find string in nested brackets
Lets say I have a string

```
uv(wh(x(yz))
```

and I want to find all string in brackets (so wh, x, yz)

```
import re
s="uuv(wh(x(yz))"

regex = r"(\(\w*?\))"
matches = re.findall(regex, s)
```

The above code only finds yz

Can I modify this regex to find all matches?

Comment: in case you don`t find a good regular expression, try this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238446/use-regular-expression-to-handle-nested-parenthesis-in-math-equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a string `split` work instead of a regex?

```
s='uv(wh(x(yz))'
match=[''.join(x for x in i if x.isalpha()) for i in s.split('(')]
>>>print(match)
['uv', 'wh', 'x', 'yz']
>>> match.pop(0)
```

You could pop off the first element because if it was contained in a parenthesis, the first position would be blank, which you wouldn't want and if it wasn't blank that means it wasn't in the parenthesis so again, you wouldn't want it.

Since that wasn't flexible enough something like this would work:

```
def match(string):
    unrefined_match=re.findall('\((\w+)|(\w+)\)', string)
    return [x for i in unrefined_match for x in i if x]

>>> match('uv(wh(x(yz))')
['wh', 'x', 'yz']

>>> match('a(b(c)de)')
['b', 'c', 'de']
```

Comment: It looks like OP doesn't want the 'uv' to match as it's not inside parens.

Comment: I can pop 'uv' but for exampel - a(bc)de .. s="a(bc)de"
match=[''.join(x for x in i if x.isalpha()) for i in s.split('(')]
print match gives ['a', 'bcde']

Comment: @Illusionist, I've updated my response. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 2):

To get all properly parenthesized text:

```
import re

def get_all_in_parens(text):
    in_parens = []
    n = "has something to substitute"       
    while n:
        text, n = re.subn(r'\(([^()]*)\)', # match flat expression in parens
                          lambda m: in_parens.append(m.group(1)) or '', text)
    return in_parens
```

Example:

```
>>> get_all_in_parens("uuv(wh(x(yz))")
['yz', 'x']
```

Note: there is no `'wh'` in the result due to the unbalanced paren.

If the parentheses are balanced; it returns all three nested substrings:

```
>>> get_all_in_parens("uuv(wh(x(yz)))")
['yz', 'x', 'wh']
>>> get_all_in_parens("a(b(c)de)")
['c', 'bde']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex a pattern such as this might potentially work:

```
\((\w{1,})
```

Result:

```
['wh', 'x', 'yz']
```

Your current pattern escapes the `(` `)` and doesn't treat them as a capture group.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt get "de" from a(b(c)de)

Comment: You didn't indicate that would be a possibility in your question!

Comment: @Illusionist Please don't go adding requirements for answers in the comments. In your question, you should give an example for every test case that you want a solution to pass. And to be frank, I find it a bit rude as well.

Comment: Thanks, sorry didn't realize that was rude.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you know how to covert from PHP regex to Python , then you can use this

```
\(((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*\)
```